# Find selectors of a specific element

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I am trying to get a list of all the selectors of a specific element using Selenium for Java.

What I want is to find a way to get all the possible selectors that the element has and save them in a list so I can call them later on and use them.

I searched for an answer but couldn't find a way to get all the selectors of a specific element.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For element with more attributes there will be immeasurably many selectors/locators. A dynamic xpath can combine attribute values even with `startswith`, `endswith`, `contains` and all of them can be used with `not`. You can create any conceivable condition for your xpath that still fit to one specific element. Amount of all conceivable selectors is infinite.

Comment: if we assume that I have an input field and I want to get all of the different selectors (css, xpath, id, etc) is there a way that I can perform that programmatically?

Comment: Yes but on page can be more elements with same id, name, class. You have to take that into account to avoid more elements matching one locator.

Comment: You can use a extension like Selectors HUB it will show all possible locators of an element

Answer (score 0):

Now a days this is a common technique used by software qa consulting companies. Fetching all elements into a list and performing selenium action w.r.t WebElement. Below is the way how to get elements into a list:

List ele_Buttons;

String xp_SelectElements = "//select";

ele_Buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xp_SelectElements));

Iterate using the below loop:

for (WebElement element : ele_Buttons)
{

// Perform the selenium action w.r.t Webelement 'element'

}